# find range hi/low by grouping values if they are separated by less than 3 positions

Tags: r

My data consists of 4 columns: date, low, high, and position.

I am trying to find the ranges by summarizing the data into groups based on the position field.

1. If diff(position) < 3, then group the data together and apply the range function to each group.
2. If diff(position) >= 3 calculate range on the current point and the previous one only.

An example of the first 15 positions, the 4th field of the data:

```
c(12,14,17,18,19,20,21,22,24,28,33,36,37,38,43)
```

and the expected outcome is to group `(12,14)` then `(17:24)`, `(24,28)`, `(28,33)`, `(33,36)`, `(36:38)`, and finally `(38,43)` and find the range for each of the groups.

Comment: I think creating a factor field along the position field which would increment by 1 at each "gap" in position that is >= 3 would solve, half of the problem, leaving the overlaps issues still open. the factor field I am thinking of would look like this c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6)

Comment: Shouldn't (14,17) also be included among the output groups?

Comment: yes you are right (14,17) should be included.  thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `diff` to identify the bounds between groups.

```
groupBy <- function(dat, thresh=3)  {
    # bounds will grab the *END* of every group (except last element)
    bounds <- which(! diff(dat) < thresh) 

    # add the last index of dat to the "stops" indecies
    stops  <- c(bounds, length(dat))

    # starts are 1 more than the bounds. We also add the first element 
    starts <- c(1, bounds+1) 

    # mapply to get `seq(starts, stops)`
    indecies <- mapply(seq, from=starts, to=stops)

    # return: lapply over each index to get the results
    lapply(indecies, function(i) dat[i])
}
```

### Testing:

```
dat1 <- c(12,14,17,18,19,20,21,22,24,28,33,36,37,38,43)
dat2 <- c(5,6,7,9,13,17,21,35,36,41)

groupBy(dat1)
groupBy(dat2)
groupBy(dat2, 5)
```

Comment: tx Ricardo I prefer using the apply family of functions, your code did that.  I appreciate all three responses.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: Oops, the code as is generates grouping error when there are back to back groups of one element.  When the data is: dat <- c(5,6,7,9,13,17,21,35,36,41) the code above grouped[[2]] return is: 13,17,21,35,36 these elements are separated by >3 but were grouped in one group.

Comment: @user2004820, great catch.  Sorry I missed it originally.  Please see the edit (now wrapped in a nice little function!)

Comment: Excellent, really appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Using `IRanges`:

```
require(IRanges)
x <- c(12,14,17,18,19,20,21,22,24,28,33,36,37,38,43)
o <- reduce(IRanges(x, width=1), min.gapwidth=2)
```

gives:

```
IRanges of length 6
    start end width
# [1]    12  14     3
# [2]    17  24     8
# [3]    28  28     1
# [4]    33  33     1
# [5]    36  38     3
# [6]    43  43     1
```

This solves half your problem. Those places where `width = 1`, you want to get appropriate previous values. So, let's convert this to a data.frame.

```
o <- as.data.frame(o)
o$start[o$width == 1] <- o$end[which(o$width == 1)-1]
o$width <- NULL

#   start end
# 1    12  14
# 2    17  24
# 3    24  28
# 4    28  33
# 5    36  38
# 6    38  43
```

That gives the final result.

**Edit:** Seems like the OP missed (14,17) in the ranges required.

```
ir <- IRanges(x, width = 1)
o1 <- reduce(ir, min.gapwidth = 2)
o2 <- gaps(o1)
start(o2) <- start(o2) - 1
end(o2) <- end(o2) + 1
o1 <- as.data.frame(o1[width(o1) > 1])
o2 <- as.data.frame(o2)
out <- rbind(o1, o2)
out <- out[with(out, order(start, end)), ]

#   start end width
# 1    12  14     3
# 4    14  17     4
# 2    17  24     8
# 5    24  28     5
# 6    28  33     6
# 7    33  36     4
# 3    36  38     3
# 8    38  43     6
```

Comment: getting familiar with the biocLite() package.  I had trouble with the installation. But its working now.  Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that uses base R functions to return a list of positional indices grouped according to the stated rule. If the values might not be monotonic, and you just care about the absolute differences, I think it would be sufficient to change `diff(x)` to `abs(diff(x))` (and remove the subsequent monotonicity check).

```
groupIndexes <- function(x, gap=3) {
    d <- diff(x)
    # currently assuming x is in increasing order
    if (any(d<0)) stop("x must be monotonically increasing")
    is.near <- (d < gap)
    # catch case of a single group
    if (all(is.near)) return(list(seq_along(x)))
    runs <- rle(ifelse(is.near, 0, seq_along(is.near)))
    gr <- rep(seq.int(runs$lengths), times=runs$lengths)
    lapply(unique(gr), function(i) {
        ind <- if(runs$values[i]>0) {
            match(i, gr)
        } else {
            which(gr==i)
        }
        c(ind, max(ind)+1)
    })
}
```

This produces this grouped values themselves:

```
x <- c(12,14,17,18,19,20,21,22,24,28,33,36,37,38,43)
lapply(groupIndexes(x), function(ind) x[ind])
```

If in your real case you have a data frame 'dat', you can generate groups based on the 'position' column and then compute group-wise ranges for the 'low' column like so:

```
lapply(groupIndexes(dat$position), function(ind) range(dat$low[ind]))
```